# Can't successfully disable Sidekiq concurrency

Tags: sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker which talks to a third-party API which is aggressively rate-limited. To avoid triggering the rate limiting my preliminary solution is to just disallow parallel processing of Sidekiq jobs. However, when I set Sidekiq's concurrency to 1, my jobs still execute in parallel.

How can I disable concurrency in Sidekiq?

Answer (score 0):

According to Mike Perham on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3190), the answer is:

> Concurrency: 1 is the correct way to limit Sidekiq to serial
>   execution.